# Is "sensitivity at fixed specificity" a valid metric for comparing different classifiers?

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, model-evaluation

For a given dataset, a common way to compare 2 classifiers is to compare their average validation accuracies using cross-validation.

Is it valid to replace the accuracy with other classification metrics that I care more about? For example, say I care about the sensitivity (recall) at a given specificity level (say 0.99). Is it still valid to compare A and B by computing the average sensitivities using cross-validation? (for each fold, train the model, plot the ROC curve, get the recall for specificity=0.99)

Comment: No; this is at the opposite end of the spectrum from decision making.  See https://www.fharrell.com/post/mlconfusion/

Comment: It's not a "no" because, in the end, it's a metric for model evaluation just like many others. The validity of the proposed metric is not in question. It's a no if someone thinks it's a good way to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can choose any metric of interest while you're validating your model.  This can be a specific metric of your choice, like sensitivity value at a specific specificity as you proposed, if you think that best suits your need; or area under ROC, precision/recall curve, F1-score etc. The space of possible choices is not limited to accuracy.